# Entity Framework Core: Get parent with all child entities where exists a child with specific criteria

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a parent entity which contains a list of children.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

EFcore will create a `ParentId` as a foreign key in the table `Child`.

Let's assume that I have several child entities with different `Type` string. I want to retrieve the parent entity including all child entities regardless of the `Type` string (i.e "Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", etc.). But first, I want to filter the child entity according to specific `Type` string, similar to `exists` in SQL query.

```
select * from Parent inner join Child ON Parent.Id = Child.ParentId
where exists (select * from Parent where Parent.Id = Child.ParentId AND Type = 'Alpha')
```

How do I achieve this using EFCore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any()`:

```
_dbContext.Parents
    .Include(p => p.Children)
    .Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => String.Equals(c.Type, "Alpha")))
    .ToList(); // or use await and ToListAsync()
```

So it queries parents (including children) that has at least one child with type equal to `Alpha`.